# IOS push to talk

Tags: ios, firebase-cloud-messaging

we are unable to use the ios push to talk framework using cloud messaging. it says that Error: Invalid [apns-push-type] set for apns platform. IOS manual says that the push type to be set to pushtotalk. but thsi s not allowed in

```
messaging().send(message)
  const message = {
    notification: {
      title: 'test'
    },
    apns: {
      headers: {
        'apns-push-type': 'pushtotalk',
        'apns-topic': 'in.etwenty.nfa.bhnonlineazan.voip-ptt',
        'apns-priority' : '10',
        'apns-expiration' : '0'
      },
      payload: {
        aps: {
          'mutable-content': 1
        }
      },
      fcm_options: {
      }
    },
    webpush: {
      headers: {
      }
    },
    topic: topicval
  }
```

pushtotalk must be accepted as valid value for apns-push-type but fcm throws an error that it is invalid.

Comment: You will probably need to call APNS directly rather than going through FCM.  You can make a feature request to FCM to support the push-to-talk type